# gsutil - copy all object that were uploaded before a specific time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I currently have a cron job that uploads a set of directories/files using r-sync. I have versioning enabled and I have a lifecycle management policy that will delete all versions that are older than 30 days.

[image: gsutil ls -la gs://rpp-XXXXXXXXX-bkup]

I am able to see the generated versions and I also see each version has a timestamp associated with it. Is it possible to download using gsutil the entire directory structure and files from GCS to local by specifying all files that are less than or equal to a specific date. The use case is to recover from the GCS backup to a specific date/time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this with a single `gsutil` command, but you could write a simple parser of the list output that filters the names objects to the time range you are interested in.  Then you could pass that as input to `gsutil cp -I`.

Note that your parser would need to reconcile the case where there was more than one version of the same file within the time range you specified.

Answer (score 2):

```
gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket | grep '2022-05-18' | awk '{print $3}' | gsutil -m cp -I ./download_dir
```

Check https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#description -I flag for reference

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).